# angular 4 bootstrap 4 radio button group, buttons won't stay checked

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

i have the following code in a angular 4 reactive form :

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" *ngFor="let item of list;let i=index" >
         <input type="radio" name="someName" [value]="item" (click)="onSelectItem(i)" formControlName="someName" [checked]="isChecked(i)"> {{item}}
         </label>
    </div>
```

onSelectItem(i) assigns the value of 'i' to a variable, isChecked(i) returns true only if i=that variable

However, the buttons won't stay checked when i click them, they just keep the same appearence, it's driving me crazy.

A fix would be greatly appreciated,
 english is my second language,
thank you and good day

Comment: Can you reproduce the same using plunker.

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/QJHmXFVNnAvFliVkF6zc/

Comment: @TomBarat What is wrong with the plunker? I don't see that it would be unchecked. Well we need to actually remove the css styling to see that in this case. So I don't see  how visually with your current styling that it would look different?

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/ in the radio button section, i want the same behavior : the radio button that is clicked changes appearence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plunker is missing the needed code to make the Bootstrap run. Add all these lines to your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Working plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/4turQ9Ubex3Xi96s5AFV/)

[Code from Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the "`data-toggle="buttons"`", the `isChecked` function will work.